# Adding Vue.JS to existing dotnet core 2.2 site

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asp.net-core

I have standard dotnet core website which uses Razor for the majority of the pages. however, there was one area, which was quite complex on the UI front, so used Vue.js for this front end. I have now come to a point where I would like to add another page. Obviously, I still want to use the dotnet core routing for the majority of the work, however, not sure how best to integrate more pages.

Are they just more individual vue apps (which could share components). or is there some other way to approach this.

My first page is rendered by dotnet core, and has a link to this js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

import { date, datetime, time } from "./filters/index.js";

Vue.filter("date", date);
Vue.filter("time", time);
Vue.filter("datetime", datetime);

new Vue({
  el: "#module-app",
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

it all works fine, (apart from a global js variable to kick off the process)

```
<div id="module-app" >
    <App :moduleId="@Model.Module.Id"></App>
</div>
```

and in a scripts section (layout master page)

```
<script>
    const ModuleId = @Model.Module.Id;
</script>

<script src="/dist/main.js" ></script>
```

This main.js file is built with webpack and bundled using npm and dependencies added with npm etc. My main worry, is actually every page I want to make will have a large download file as it contains vue.js etc and all components.

There must be a better way, so a solution would be good to know. All the examples talk about the vue router (which i have used) but not sure how it can work with the whole dotnet core routing too.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Those file should be cached and not downloaded again. So that's nothing to worry about.

Comment: I know I could make vue.js stand alone by just linking to it in the master layout and remove it from the dependencies (unless that breaks nuget if it thinks it is not referenced?) but how to configure webpack? Do they get built separately, or can we have multiple entrance points (I see it is an array...) Any advice to migrate - all new code would be nice to use vue.js